# What are the commonly confused encodings that may result in identical test data?

Tags: character-encoding, utf-8, ascii

I'm fixing code that is using ASCIIEncoding in some places and UTF-8 encoding in other functions.

Since we aren't using the UTF-8 features, all of our unit tests passed, but I want to create a heightened awareness of encodings that produce similar results and may not be fully tested.

I don't want to limit this to just UTF-8 vs ASCII, since I think issue with code that handles ASN.1 fields and other code working with Base64.

So, what are the commonly confused encodings that may result in identical test data?

Comment: is it an XML or varchar in DB table? what type of document and where you use encoding?

Comment: @ElYusubov  I have many questions that relate to converting [this ASN.1 data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269079/328397) and updating pre existing code to C#

Comment: you may need to tag questions in more helpful way, i just tried to clarify. Thx for link though.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Codepages and Extended ASCII support are virtually guaranteed to throw you a curveball.

Answer (score 0):

For MIME the following headers may produce similar results:

- Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii (Plain text)
- Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 (a superset of ASCII)
- Content-type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-2" (another superset of ASCII)
- Content-type: text/enriched; charset="windows-1252" (if there are no enriched codes)

Comment: Is `latin1` synonymous with `ISO-8859-2`, or might it be another "superset of ASCII" that could be useful?

Comment: Latin1 is ISO-8859-1.